# Generating data for image processing

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection

I am new to Deep learning and I am working on a hobby project related to soccer sports analytics. I want to use soccer videos and convert them on to a 2D map. I have broken down the process into smaller steps. The first step is to be able to detect players and the soccer ball.

I am thinking of starting with a pre-trained object detection model. I have taken a video and generated images from it. I used that on one of the images and I have attached the output. It is clearly not picking up on a lot of things. One way to solve this is to do some transfer learning. For that, I will have to generate my own dataset. The only way I can think of is to slice this image into windows and label them manually as players and soccer ball.

This seems like a tedious task. Are there other efficient ways of generating data? What are some best practices?

[image]

Comment: Data labelling is tedious, period. You can upload your images on Amazon Turk for people to tag for a price, or you can use your existing model (if good enough) to generate boxes that you will only have to correct.

Comment: I am just using the object detection model with no modification. It is clearly not picking up on a lot of the players. Unfortunately, it isn't generating misclassified boxes to correct either. yeah! Data labeling is tedious! Will check out Amazon Turk. Thank you.

Comment: A common technique is to run the model, keep the good detections, rerun the model with these detections, rinse and repeat. You should get more and more labels. It won't replace your job, as you'll still have to curate the outputs, but it can avoid you needing to do every single label by hand. Oh and obviously data augmentation is key with small datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more likely for long-run development, but as I already wrote a similar answer so posting it here.

1. First create a dataset of the players with bounding boxes (around 500-1k, then use augmentation to make a few more thousands). You can use the following tools for annotating:

https://github.com/developer0hye/Yolo_Label (works great, but only for windows)

https://github.com/AlexeyAB/Yolo_mark

https://github.com/heartexlabs/label-studio (this is a more complex annotation tool for many other tasks)

With these tools, it should not take more than few hours to annotate the data.

There are many augmentation tools like - https://github.com/mdbloice/Augmentor

https://github.com/wagonhelm/rotation_augment (If you want to use rotation on the images)

2. As the players will be moving you need something with a good FPS and also a reasonable mAP. From my experiments with many object detection models, I have found yolov3 (darknet) to be the most stable.

I would suggest to go with darknet YOLO, which is written in C++, you wouldn't need to write any major code, it will be fast and accurate.

https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/

Use this repo if you're on Linux https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet

Use this one if you're on Windows https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet

3. Before training, you need to find the optimal anchor size for your dataset. I wrote a simple k-means to find the anchor size in any yolo-compatible dataset.

https://github.com/zabir-nabil/yolov3-anchor-clustering

4. I did some minor customization (like sending OpenCV/numpy arrays directly to model) to run the darknet python API faster on a server (tensorflow model server with both REST and gRPC). I also wrote a flask server for it. You can find it here -

https://github.com/zabir-nabil/tf-model-server4-yolov3

There are some pre-trained models (you'll easily find them on github) for pedestrians but they won't give you a very good performance due to very different background and also the motion artifacts.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to annotate data using the tools mentioned in point 1. I will definitely check out darknet. Can you explain point 3 a little? What do you mean by optimal anchor size? Is that number of data points for each class?